# A bash/gnuplot script to produce movie-like effects

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I would like to plot a sequence of images one after the other on the same window using gnuplot. Images are all the same exact size and I have many of them sequentially called test_0X.gnu and are in gnuplot format.

I wrote this in bash

```
 #! /bin/bash

for i in $(seq -f "%06g" 0 1000)
do
echo "set term pdf enhance color" > script.plg
echo "set output 'demo.pdf'" >> script.plg

echo "plot 'test_$i.gnu' with lines" >> script.plg
echo "set output"

gnuplot < script.plg

evince demo.pdf &
sleep 0.3

done;
```

The seq -f ensures the correct number of padded zeros is present before the number.

This works but once the script starts I am unable to stop it, as `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+z` doesn't work and I cannot access other terminal due to constant coming up of a pdf windows.

- How do I stop this?
- How do I make the sequence skip (e.g. by 10) and show me only test_000010.gnu, test_000020.gnu, .. etc.
- Bonus: Any other, more sensible way to do this is welcome.

Comment: why dont you create PDFs with $i in it so you have one output for each input? I would not open the PDF viewer at all, then it is better to handle. You can manually look at some of them. You should be able to stop it then (or you log in remotely and kill it from another session). If you really want to show only ever tenth, you can use a extra counter: `c=$[c+1]; if [ $[c%10] = 0 ]; then evince demo.pdf; fi`.

Comment: I need to produce a sort of video to look for visible changes, I have no need for the single files. Also, I have something like 10.000 of these, maybe more in the future, so I don't want produce these many pdf files.

Comment: Then it would be best to produce an animated gif or a real video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a short gnuplot script

```
set terminal wxt
files = system('ls test_*.gnu')
do for [file in files] {
    plot file with lines
    pause 0.5
}
```

and run this

Comment: Awesome, gnuplot script have much more capabilities than I tought. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

gnuplots "gif" terminal can produce a readymade animation.

```
skip=5 # change as needed
set term gif animate 10 # 10/100 s delay between frames
set out "test.gif"
# assuming your data files are named "test_0001.dat" etc.
do for [i=1:100:skip] {plot sprintf("test_%04.f.dat",i)}
set out
```